# pdf file output created with FPDF are empty (PHP)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Hi and thanks by advance for you helps.

I'm trying to write on a PDF with FPDF on PHP.

I'm actually working on WordPress.

If I'm using this code on my first website, it's working well:

```
if (isset($_GET["obtenir-mon-analyse"])){
  $pdfFile = getcwd() . '/wp-content/themes/childtheme/ressources/PDF_analyse_template.pdf';
  require_once('library/fpdf/fpdf.php');
  require_once('library/fdpi/src/autoload.php');

  // initiate FPDI
  $pdf = new setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi();
  // add a page
  $pdf->AddPage("L");
  // set the source file
  $pdf->setSourceFile($pdfFile);
  // import page 1
  $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
  // use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
  $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0,0 );

  $pdf->Output('I');

}
```

But, with the same code on another website, the PDF generated by the output function is empty (0kb).

Also, the template is working because FDPF is well detecting the available page number.

PS:

- The 2 website are hosting on the same host.
- I have not any error.

I really don't know where is the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey there, it's quite impossible for anyone to provide support without more info.
What are the differences between the two websites? Same or different hosting? Have you checked the server logs for errors? Have you tried to add try/catch to print any exception from the FPDF class?

Answer (score 0):

I think nobody will see this answer but:

- On wordpress
- With the plugin WP-optimize
- If you use the mimify option on HTML, you will not be able to use FPDF